# Issue with setting Tag for button in sectioned UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have two buttons inside sectioned tableview cell thumbs up and thumbs down. Initially image of both button is not selected. When I select thumbs up button its image become thumbs up selected and other one become thumbsdown not selected and vice versa.

```
//Number of sections
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
{
    NSLog(@"mod:numberOfSectionsInTableView");
    NSLog(@"[preferences count]=%d",[preferences count]);
    return  [preferences count];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.choices count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexpath
{
    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath: DISPLAY TEST");  
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        NSLog(@"Text is: %@", [choices objectAtIndex:indexpath.row]);                   
        NSLog(@"CHOICE AT INDEX PATH IS: %@",[choices objectAtIndex:indexpath.row %[choices count]]);
        cell.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


        // Thumbs up button.
        //UIButton *thumbsUp = [[UIButton alloc]init];  
        thumbsUp = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];                        
        [thumbsUp setTag:(indexpath.row+(indexpath.section * 50))];
        [thumbsUp addTarget:self action:@selector(thumbUp_ButtonClicked:event:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];     
        [thumbsUp setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        thumbsUp.frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 20, 20, 15);
        [thumbsUp setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbsup_not_selected.png"]
     forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        //NSLog(@"------------------>TAG TEST : %d",(indexpath.row+(indexpath.section * 50)));
        [cell.contentView addSubview:thumbsUp];

        // Thumbs down button

        thumbsDown = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [thumbsDown addTarget:self  action:@selector(thumbDown_ButtonClicked:event:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [thumbsDown setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        thumbsDown.frame = CGRectMake(200, 20, 20, 15);

        [thumbsDown setTag:indexpath.row+120];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:thumbsDown];
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];


        [thumbsDown setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbsdown_not_selected.png"]
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    NSLog(@"------------> TAG TEST %d",thumbsUp.tag);
    cell.text = [choices objectAtIndex:(indexpath.row % [choices count])];


    NSLog(@"HELLO FOR TESTING");
    return cell;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
    if (sectionTitle == nil) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create label with section title
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(15, 10, 300, 25);
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    label.text = sectionTitle;


    // Create header view and add label as a subview
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 0, 300, 60)];
    [view autorelease];
    [view addSubview:label];
    //[view addSubview:segmentedControl];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    return view;
}

//Thumbs Up Button Action

- (IBAction)thumbUp_ButtonClicked:(id)sender event:(id)event
{
    NSLog(@"Thumbs Up Check!");


    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [[button superview] superview];


    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [myTable indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"indexpath =%d",indexPath.row);
    //[button setTag:indexPath.row+(indexPath.section * 50)];

    int cTag = [sender tag];
    NSLog(@"------>TAG : %d", cTag);
    NSLog(@"------> Calculated TAG %d",indexPath.row+(indexPath.section * 50));
    if(cTag == (indexPath.row+(indexPath.section * 50)))
    {
        NSLog(@"BUTTON COUNT:");
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbsup_selected.png"]
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }enter code here


    NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    //int row = button.tag;

    NSLog(@"SECTION IS:%d",section);
    NSLog(@"ROW IS: %d",row);


    NSArray *array = cell.contentView.subviews;
    NSLog(@"NUMBER OF OBJECTS: %d",[array count]);
    UIButton *test = (UIButton *)[array objectAtIndex:2];

    [test setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumbsdown_not_selected.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];

}
```

Due to issue with tag of button while I change image of one button several buttons are changing.

If any one can please find a solution it will be helpful.... tag is setting for buttons in sections which we can view.

If the Tableview is not sectioned its working well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem *might* be the fact that you're setting the variable only if the cell is newly created. Perhaps the sectioning has an impact on how many cells are affected. Try pulling your  thumbs up / thumbs down code out of the if (cell == nil) block and see if that has an effect.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the above solution. But the problem is while scrolling the tableView change the image of the button.....